# How to display operating system in PowerCLI

Tags: powercli

Im using the following powerCLI script to display:

1. VM Name
2. Uptime
3. Operating system

However the operating system part of the script returns a blank value.

```
#connect to server, setup reportfile
$VIServer="servername"

Connect-VIServer -Server servername

$stat = 'sys.osuptime.latest'

$entity = Get-VM

Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat -Realtime -MaxSamples 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |

Select @{N='VM';E={$_.Entity.Name}},

    @{N='Uptime (d.hh:mm:ss)';E={[timespan]::FromSeconds($_.value)}},
    @{N=”Configured OS”;E={$_.ExtensionData.Config.GuestFullname}}
```

Output:

VM                  : VM_EXAMPLE
Uptime (d.hh:mm:ss) : 00.07:29:04
Configured OS       :

If I run:

```
Get-VM | Select @{Label = "VM Name" ; Expression = {$_.Name} },@{N=”Configured OS”;E={$_.ExtensionData.Config.GuestFullname}}
```

The operating system displays fine.

Any ideas on how I can get the os to display?

Answer (score 0):

You're piping in the `Get-Stat` Which doesn't contain the details in the `$entity` variable.

```
... | Select @{N='VM';E={$_.Entity.Name}},
    @{N='Uptime (d.hh:mm:ss)';E={[timespan]::FromSeconds($_.value)}},
    @{N=”Configured OS”;E={$entity.ExtensionData.Config.GuestFullname}}
```